# PSQLException: this ResultSet is closed

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, resultset

i've occours this strange error for the first time in my life, and i don't know what does it means. I've a class that retrieve information from a table on a postgresql database, do some operations and return an arraylist with parsed element:

```
ResultSet rs = ProduttoreDCS.getProduttori();
        System.out.println("Recuperato result set produttori");
        ArrayList<String[]> res = new ArrayList<String[]>();


        while (rs.next()) {
            String[] current = new String[6];

            current[0] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("partita_iva"));
            current[1] = rs.getString("nome");
            current[2] = rs.getString("cognome");
            current[3] = rs.getString("via_sede");
            current[4] = rs.getString("citta_sede");
            current[5] = rs.getString("provincia_sede");

            res.add(current);
            current = null;
        }

        return res;
```

the error is on "while" line.

```
public static ResultSet getProduttori() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    /*
     * retrieve all record from produttori table
     */
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM produttore";

    conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    System.out.println("Connection obtained by ProduttoreDCS class");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    res = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    stmt.close();
    conn.close();


    return res;   
}
```

Comment: show us getProduttori() method

Comment: What does `getProduttori` do, exactly? If it tries to reuse the same ResultSet object multiple times, that could easily be the problem. (There's no reason to set `current` to `null` by the way.)

Comment: @jon skeet i know, just remove it! EDITED main post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you close the **connection object** in your `getProduttori` method, your **result set** will be automatically *closed*. when you try to re use it , it will be null.

```
ResultSet rs = ProduttoreDCS.getProduttori();
             = null, as you have closed the connection in getProduttori
               method, which will automatically close the resultset 
               thus, it returns null.
```

From **[Connection#close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29)**

> Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources
>   immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released.

applies same when closing the Statement as well.For your code to work don't close Statement and Connection untill you get the rows.

@Baadshah has already shown you the standard way. If you are using java 7+ you can make use of try-with-resource block, which would make your life simpler.

```
 try(Connection conn = gettheconn){
     get the statement here
     get the result set 
      perform your ops
 }
 catch(SQLException ex){
   ex.printstacktrace(); 
  }
```

If you observe, there is no finally block, your connection object will be closed once you exit the try block automatically.you don't have to explicity call Connection#close()

Comment: so i just need to move first portion of code inside getProduttori method and return the ArrayList to caller method?

Comment: yepp, thats indeed the standard way of doing it

Comment: yeah, i forced my team to upgrade to java 7 just so i can skip all those finally block drama when using JDBC. :P

Answer (score 10):

I've encountered the same problem by running the wrong combination of:

Postgres version;
Hibernate dialect;
postgres jdbc driver;

Updating all to the latest version solved the problem for me.

*P.S. I know this is not what OP was asking, but this is the first result in Google when you search for the problem.*

Comment: It works for me. make sure that the postgres version is supported by postgres jdbc lib on your project. If you are running the PostgreSQL 9.6, then use PostgreSQL JDBC 9.

Answer (score 5):

[As per Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> **A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed**, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You are closed the connection and then you are iterating ,where it is null.Please read the data and then close the connection.

A good practice here is

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    conn = 
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("sql");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
   //DO SOME THING HERE
} catch {
    // Error Handling
} finally {
    try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
}
```

Comment: i heart `try with resource` from java 7 :)

Comment: @PermGenError yeah yeah ..this is existing code :) Haaav ..have to move java 7 :P

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

You're closing the connection to the database. You can't do that until you've read the data - otherwise how is the `ResultSet` going to read it? Maybe it will have read *some* data in to start with, but it's not meant to be a disconnected object.

In particular, from the docuemntation for `ResultSet.close`:

> Note: A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it when that Statement object is closed, re-executed, or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the connection makes the resultSet go away.

A ResultSet is not a container you can use to pass data around in, it's only a wrapper around a cursor.  You should run through the resultSet contents and copy them into a data structure, then return the data structure. You are already doing that, but you need to do it before closing the statement and connection.

Change the code to:

```
public static List<String[]> getProduttori() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    ArrayList<String[]> res = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    /*
     * retrieve all record from produttori table
     */
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM produttore";

    conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    try {
        System.out.println("Connection obtained by ProduttoreDCS class");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String[] current = new String[6];
                current[0] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("partita_iva"));
                current[1] = rs.getString("nome");
                current[2] = rs.getString("cognome");
                current[3] = rs.getString("via_sede");
                current[4] = rs.getString("citta_sede");
                current[5] = rs.getString("provincia_sede");
                res.add(current);
            }        
            return res;
        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try {
        conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: THe problem with this is if you want to abstract away the database calls into a separate class, this becomes difficult with this technique because here you are mixing in data of class with database connection methods.

Comment: @John: agreed, I would prefer to use spring here with spring-jdbc keeping the connection-acquiring completely separate. it just didn't seem to me like that was part of the question.